# Copying Files with Certain Names and ascending numbers from a List

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

I have a folder with a few thousand pdf files that are named a certain way and a list of files I want to copy to another folder.

```
- "abcd0000000001-00.pdf"
- "abcd0000000001-01.pdf"
- "abcd0000000001-02.pdf"  // copy abcd0000000001-02.pdf
- "abcd0000000002-00.pdf"
- "abcd0000000002-01.pdf"
- "abcd0000000002-02.pdf"
- "abcd0000000002-03.pdf"  // copy abcd0000000002-03.pdf
- "abcd0000000003-00.pdf"
- "abcd0000000003-01.pdf"
- "abcd0000000004-00.pdf"
- "abcd0000000004-01.pdf"  
- "abcd0000000004-02.pdf"
- "abcd0000000004-03.pdf"
- "abcd0000000004-04.pdf"  // copy abcd0000000004-04.pdf
- ...
- "abcd000000000n-nn.pdf" //  copy abcd000000000n-[highest].pdf
```

I don't want to copy every pdf file, only the one with the highest ascending number of each file.

I have found this [code](https://superuser.com/a/1236617/969781) of [Vomit IT - Chunky Mess Style](https://superuser.com/users/510662/vomit-it-chunky-mess-style)

```
FOR /F "USEBACKQ TOKENS=*" %F IN ("C:\Folder\FileList.txt") DO XCOPY /F /Y "C:\SourceFolder\%~F" "C:\DestinationFolder\"
```

How can I edit this line of code to get the highest ascending number each time?

Comment: Pick the highest number after the hyphen for each file group that has the same name considering the part before the hyphen correct?

Comment: yes that is correct.

Comment: I wonder why this question got so many upvotes so quickly...

Answer (score 1):

Another answer that will not need for batches or codes ,  you have workable features in tools like Syncback and Gs Richcopy that supports Wildcard to include/exclude files , try to contact them for free trial

Answer (score 0):

- From your file list...

List your files in a `For /F` loop and get the strings e that return in the first token (default) and set `-` as your delimiter, then list filtering your files by name in reverse order, copy the first one if not exist in destination folder...

```bat
@echo off

cd/d "D:\The\Full\Path\To\Your\.Pdf\Files\Folder"
set "_list=D:\The\Full\Path\To\Your\List\File.txt"
set "_target=D:\The\Full\Path\To\Your\Target\Folder"

for /f "usebackdelims=-" %%a in (`type "%_list%"^|findstr \-[0-9][0-9]\.pdf
   `)do for /f "tokens=*delims=-" %%i in ('dir /o:-n /a:-d /b "%%~a-??.pdf"
       ')do if not exist "%_target%\%%~a-??.pdf" ;copy "%%~fi" "%_target%\"
```

---

- Without file list

List your files by name in reverse order `/o-n`, copy each file when it doesn't exist in your folder, assuming/replacing `-NumberNumber` delimiter with `-??`.

```bat
@echo off 

cd /d "D:\The\Full\Path\To\Your\.Pdf\Files\Folder"
set "_Target_Dir=D:\The\Full\Path\To\Your\Target\Folder"

for /f tokens^=1*delims^=- %%i in ('dir /o-n /a-d /b *-??.pdf
   ')do if not exist "%_Target_Dir%\%%~i-??.pdf" copy "%%~i-%%~j" "%_Target_Dir%"
```

---

**Additional resources:**

- [`Dir /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html)
- [`Set /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)
- [`For /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
- [`For /F /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)

  - [`For /F commands`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)
- [`If Condition() Else If Condition() Else()`](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)
- [How does the Windows Command Interpreter [`cmd.exe`] Parse Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4094699/6819406)

Comment: The files to be copied should be taken from a file list *.txt not from the source folder from what I got, but this probably works anyway.

Comment: @RicardoBohner thank you, now I see this one.... d;)

Comment: I suspect that the files in the file list txt are the same as in the source folder....

Answer (score 0):

Try this batch file. You copy the following code to notepad and edit this part according to your neeeds:

```
:: Set the location of the file list here:
set List=c:\files.txt
:: Set the location of the source files here:
set Source=c:\Source
:: Set the location of the desired destination here:
set Destiny=c:\Destiny
```

Then you save the file with the name that you want but with a *.bat extension and and double click it.

```
@echo off

:: Set the location of the file list here:
set List=c:\files.txt
:: Set the location of the source files here:
set Source=c:\Source
:: Set the location of the desired destination here:
set Destiny=c:\Destiny

if not exist "%List%" echo  Error: The file list doesn't seem to exist& pause& exit
if not exist "%Source%" echo Error: The Source folder doesn't seem to exist& pause& exit

if not exist "%Destiny%" md "%Destiny%"
set NameA=
set NameB=

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('type "%List%" ^|find /i "-" ^|sort /r') do call :CopyL "%%~a"

pause
exit

:CopyL

for /f "tokens=1* delims=-" %%a in ("%~1") do (
                                               if not "%NameA%"=="%%a" copy "%Source%\%~1" "%Destiny%\"
                                               set NameA=%%a
                                               set NameB=%%b
                                              )

goto :EOF
```

As you can see on my test environment it only copies the files of a group with the highest number and ignores files that down't have a hyphen in the name (new york):

[CopyFiles.gif](https://i.imgur.com/wGBLMQQ.gif)